# JSF-Spring deploy to weblogic

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic

I m trying deploy to my new web gui.

But I wanna ask something about my weblogic.xml

this is my weblogic.xml :

```
 <wls:weblogic-web-app
 xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd
 http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
 http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

      <wls:weblogic-version>12.1.1</wls:weblogic-version>
      <wls:context-root>FilterWeb</wls:context-root>
      <wls:container-descriptor>
          <wls:prefer-application-packages>
              <wls:package-name>com.oracle.foo</wls:package-name>
          </wls:prefer-application-packages>
      </wls:container-descriptor>
 </wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

**So, here is my question :** How can I set the "use my all packet" just a one line?

At this way I have to set all package name under this command : wls:prefer-application-packages

But I dont wanna write all packages name. Because I have a lot of package.

Anyone knows anything about this? I cant find anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way around it, you have to list all of the application packages you want to "prefer" over the Weblogic default. The best you can hope for is to add a `*` on the end to capture all of the packages you want at some package level.

Are you really using that many packages outside of the Weblogic default?

See the Oracle docs: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#autoId24) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/app_xml.htm#WLPRG444)